# Forward parametr in page

Tags: java, jsf, param

I have a panelAdmin page and when i click adminList i forward the parameter

```
            <h:commandLink value="Admini" action="#{userMB.adminList()}">
                <f:param name="userId" value="#{loginMB.user.id}" />
            </h:commandLink>
```

UserMB method

```
public String adminList() {
    return "adminList";
}
```

and faces-config:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/adminPanel.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>adminList</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/adminList.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
```

my adminList page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <h:head>
        <title>Lista adminow</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h3>Zalogwano jako: #{loginMB.user.firstName} #{loginMB.user.firstName}</h3>
        <h3>Lista administratorów</h3>
        <f:view>
            <h:form>
                <p:dataTable value="#{userMB.allAdmins}" var="admin" widgetVar="customerTable">
                    <p:column headerText="Imie">
                        #{admin.firstName}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Nazwisko">
                        #{admin.lastName}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Pesel">
                        #{admin.personalId}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Edytuj">  
                        <h:commandLink value="Edytuj" action="#{userMB.editStart()}">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{userMB.user}" value="#{admin}" />
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Usun">
                        <h:commandLink value="Usun" action="#{userMB.deleteUser()}">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{userMB.user}" value="#{admin}" />
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                <h:commandButton value="add" action="#{userMB.createStart()}"/>
                <h:commandButton value="back" action="/adminPanel.xhtml"/>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

And when I click the add button or back button i have a error: HTTP Status 500

```
type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.
```

in glassfish server logs:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pl.ePrzychodnia.mb.UserMB.getAllAdmins(UserMB.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:729)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:575)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowModel(UIData.java:405)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:397)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:254)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:223)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:933)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

UserMB

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UserMB {

    @EJB
    private UserFacadeLocal userFacade;
    private User user;

    public List<User> getAllAdmins() {
        return userFacade.findAllAdmins();
    }
```

UserFacade

```
@Stateless
public class UserFacade implements UserFacadeLocal {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @EJB
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public List<User> findAllAdmins() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map requestParameterMap = (Map) context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String paramId = requestParameterMap.get("userId").toString();
        Integer userId = Integer.parseInt(paramId);
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u where u.role = 'admin' and u.id <> :id");
        q.setParameter("id", userId);
        List<User> users = q.getResultList();
        return users;
    }
```

Comment: So what's in line 51 of `UserMB.java`? Post the bean code please.

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace it looks like `UserFacadeLocal` is not getting injected into `UserMB`. Place a breakpoint in `getAllAdmins` method and verify if that's the case.